# open a portion of image in new window using area map

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am trying to create an epaper as shown on the link

http://cantact104.com/show-jobs/

I have created many areas using area property

but now I want is that when I click on any area then it opens in new windown

How can I achieve it

Comment: If the "area" is an <a> tag, use "target='new'" or the like.

Comment: but I would like to open that portion of image only

Comment: So your question isn't how to open something in a new window, it's how to just show that area on a new page?  How about give each area an ID, and pass that ID to PHP which then shows that area only?